# Larger WCF messages via MSMQ not processed

Tags: .net, wcf, msmq

I have a Windows Console App hosting a WCF service that reads from an MSMQ. When the message size gets to around 7k to 8k the service reads it (i.e. it disappears from the Q) but the appropriate function isn't called. No exceptions thrown. Anybody have any clues about what's happening or where to look to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

I tracked down the problem. In the .config file of the hosting app/service add or change the maxStringContentLength attribute of the readerQuotas element which defaults to 8196.

```
<bindings>
  <netMsmqBinding>
    <binding name="netMsmq">
      <security mode="None" />
      <readerQuotas
        maxDepth="32"
        maxStringContentLength="8196"
        maxArrayLength="16384"
        maxBytesPerRead="4096"
        maxNameTableCharCount="16384"
        />
    </binding>
  </netMsmqBinding>
</bindings>
```